# How do I get the columnID from this json string?

Tags: php, json

Struggling to get the columnid field from this string. Not that familiar with JSON strings.

The code I used to get the string is

```
$result = json_decode($challenge);
```

Which returns this string

```
{"nonce":"9c7c67b7-862c-4acf-b45c-3a2917e2af5e","timestamp":"2021-02-11T14:45:33.636+0000","webhookId":2210751436875652,"scope":"sheet","scopeObjectId":977785561868164,"events":[{"objectType":"cell","eventType":"updated","rowId":8881477381056388,"columnId":947011108267908,"userId":3106431567193988,"timestamp":"2021-02-11T14:43:22.000+0000"}]}
```

I have tried
$result->events->columnid. but no luck

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @develogg correctly sujects to switch to associative array format. But your `events` contains an array of events, which you can not simply address. Instead you should take the events and find the need element using columnId as a predicate, e.g. you may use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php or a simple manual loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode($challenge, true)`and you will get your JSON on array.
And you'll be able to make `$result['events'][0][$columnId]`

Comment: `$result['events'][0]['columnId']` please :)